# Using #include <algorithm> to sort a vector of class objects by a string data member

Tags: c++, algorithm, stl

Suppose I have this class:

```
class cat
{
    private:
        int age;
        string name;

    public:
        cat();
        ~cat();

        void set_age(int a) { age = a; }
        void set_name(string n) { name = n; } 

        int get_age() { return age; }
        string get_name() { return name; }
}
```

And I have an unsorted vector with objects of the class `cat` called `vector<cat> cats` or something. How would I use the algorithm STL to sort them by name?

Comment: What don't you understand about it? Did you read some documentation? There must be a million examples all over the web.

Comment: Please do not fundamentally change a question once it's been posted and has gathered answers.

Answer (score 0):

The function implements the "lesser-than" ordering. It takes two arbitrary elements, and returns which one is the lesser of the two. The container's internal algorithm uses that to create the ordering.

I have to say, this is made quite clear by [`std::sort`'s documentation](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort):

> **comp:** comparison function object (i.e. an object that satisfies the requirements of Compare) which returns `​true` if the first argument is *less* than (i.e. is ordered *before*) the second.
>
> The signature of the comparison function should be equivalent to the following:
>
> ```
> bool cmp(const Type1 &a, const Type2 &b);
> ```

So I'm not sure what you're struggling with? You didn't say.

Comment: I suppose I am curious as to how this works when the data type you are trying to sort is a string. My apologies. If it's merely an `a < b` type of comparison, would it still sort alphabetically?

Comment: @Jordan: That's entirely up to you! You're writing the function, so you define the ordering. That's why you're able to define it yourself. If your "container" is a `string` then you are defining an ordering over `char`s. Well, as long as you abide by the _strict weak ordering_. Which book are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Update: now you've changed the question from how to sort by age to how to sort by name... I assume you can adapt the code below.

It can be as simple as

```
std::sort(std::begin(cats), std::end(cats),
          [](const cat& x, const cat& y)
          { return x.get_age() < y.get_age(); });
```

but if - as in the real world - cats may have the same age - fall back on some other criterion to determine which is "less" - in your case the only option is `name`, so:

```
std::sort(std::begin(cats), std::end(cats),
          [](const cat& x, const cat& y)
          { return x.get_age() < y.get_age() ||
                   x.get_age() == y.get_age() && x.get_name() < y.get_name(); });
```

The third parameter is the sorting function that says if the first parameter - above `x` - is less than the second - `y`.  I've used an inline lambda function, which has been supported since C++11.